# Using rollmean when there are missing values (NA)

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I have a data set which has a couple of `NA` in it. I take a rolling mean and expect that when there is no `NA` in the window, the rolling mean should produce a number as opposed to `NA`, however, `rollmeanr` in `zoo` does not seem to do this. Example:

```
require(zoo)
z = zoo(cbind(a=0:10, b=c(NA,10:1), c=sample(1:11,11)), 1:11) 
rollmeanr(z, k=3, fill=NA)
    a  b        c
1  NA NA       NA
2  NA NA       NA
3   1 NA 3.333333
4   2 NA 4.666667
5   3 NA 4.000000
6   4 NA 6.333333
7   5 NA 7.000000
8   6 NA 9.333333
9   7 NA 8.333333
10  8 NA 8.666667
11  9 NA 5.666667

rollapply(z, width=3, FUN=mean, by=1, by.column=TRUE, fill=NA, align="right")
    a  b        c
1  NA NA       NA
2  NA NA       NA
3   1 NA 3.333333
4   2  9 4.666667
5   3  8 4.000000
6   4  7 6.333333
7   5  6 7.000000
8   6  5 9.333333
9   7  4 8.333333
10  8  3 8.666667
11  9  2 5.666667
```

I would expect these two calls to generate the same result. Please comment. Some session info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] zoo_1.7-10

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] grid_3.0.1      lattice_0.20-15
```

Comment: From the help file I have : `The default method of ‘rollmean’ does not
     handle inputs that contain ‘NA’s. In such cases, use ‘rollapply’
     instead.`

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I assumed that It would just not allow you to skip over NA as rollapply allows you to pass na.rm=TRUE. Should that be read as it breaks when there are NA?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From `?rollmean`

> The default method of ‘rollmean’ does not
>        handle inputs that contain ‘NA’s. In such cases, use ‘rollapply’
>        instead.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I assumed that It would just not allow you to skip over NA as rollapply allows you to pass na.rm=TRUE. Should that be read as it breaks when there are NA?

Comment: Look at `zoo:::rollmean.zoo` and note that `na.rm` is not passed anywhere.

Comment: yeh, that's not what i was saying though. i thought `na.rm=FALSE` would be the default and you can't modify that in `rollmean` where as you can modify that in `rollapply`. That's what I understood the help file to be saying. Obviously I was incorrect.

Comment: You could always use 'filter' function. It has no problems with NAs and very fast

Comment: @GeorgeSteblovsky Yes, `as.zoo(apply(z, 2, function(x) filter(x, rep(1/3, 3), sides=1)))` is about 9 times faster in this case.

Comment: @GeorgeSteblovsky while `NA`s are *allowed* using `filter()`, they pollute the output much more than they do in `rollapply` - try `x <- c(5, 7, 10, NA, 3, 6, 2, NA, 1, 9); as.numeric(filter(x, rep(1/3, 3))); zoo::rollapply(x, 3, mean, na.rm=TRUE)` and compare the output.

Answer (score 8):

Use 'partial=TRUE' option. The option makes it possible to calculate data with NA.

```
> rollapply(z, width=3, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), by=1, by.column=TRUE, partial=TRUE, fill=NA, align="right")

     a    b        c
1  0.0  NaN 1.000000
2  0.5 10.0 5.500000
3  1.0  9.5 4.333333
4  2.0  9.0 6.666667
5  3.0  8.0 4.666667
6  4.0  7.0 6.000000
7  5.0  6.0 7.000000
8  6.0  5.0 8.666667
9  7.0  4.0 8.333333
10 8.0  3.0 7.000000
11 9.0  2.0 5.000000
```

If you want to change 'NaN' in the first row to '0', modify 'fill=NA' to 'fill=0'.

Comment: or equivalently: `rollapplyr(z, 3, mean, na.rm = TRUE, by = 1, partial = TRUE, fill = NA)`

Comment: Is it possible to calculate the mean for cells only when the original value was NA? In other words can original values be kept while imputing averages within the given window only where the original values were NA? Similar to na.fill(x, 'extend') but with a limit to which it 'extends' being the window or width.

Comment: @Nebulloyd
I think your question is about 'mean imputation'. https://statisticsglobe.com/mean-imputation-for-missing-data/

Comment: @JKim Unfortunately no I am not. The key difference is that the mean should only be calculated over a small 'window' in the column. The examples in your link fill all NAs of a column with the same mean value (column mean). I am using a time series data set so I expect the values directly before or after to be more similar to missing NAs than the column mean. I also want long streaks of NA larger than a certain value to remain NA.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck it gives NaN when there aren't any values until the k window has enough entries.

Comment: @SqueakyBeak, That is not how it works. If you use `partial=TRUE` and `na.rm = TRUE` it only gives NaN if the entire window is NA; otherwise, it gives the mean of the non-NAs even if the window is shorter than 3.  If you want to use 0, say, in the case that the entire window is NA then use `mean0 <- function(x) c(na.omit(mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)), 0)[1];
rollapplyr(z, 3, mean0, partial = TRUE)` or replace 0 with whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

To make it complete, rollsum can not handle inputs that contain ‘NA’s as well. In such cases, use ‘rollapply’ instead.