# roll mean based on conditions in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, data.table, moving-average

I want to use moving average function (`rollmean`) in R. Example data:

```
x<-seq(1,48,by=1)
y<-c(rep(11,12), rep(12,12))
z<-data.frame(x,y)
```

I want to calculate moving average of the `z[,"x"]` with lag of 3 days for each `z[,"y"]` (i.e. 11 & 12) and filled them to the (new) third column where first two rows of each `z[,"y"]` are designated by `NAs`.

Comment: What have you tried? That could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765001/using-rollmean-when-there-are-missing-values-na

Comment: Any reason to use `data.table` instead of a dataframe? Why is `y` shorter than `x`?  I'm pretty sure you can do this in one line using `rollapply(x, widths={something to do with y},...)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `zoo` for example using the `data.table` package:

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(z)
DT[, roll_x := rollmeanr(x, 3, fill = NA), y]
```

Of course if have some missing values it is better to use `rollapplyr` :

```
DT[, roll_x := rollapplyr(x, 3, mean, fill = NA), y]
```

Another package that is going to be faster is `caTools`:

```
library(caTools)
DT[, roll_x := runmean(x, 3, align = 'right', endrule = 'NA'), by = y]
```

In terms of data frames this works too:

```
transform(z, roll_x = ave(x, y, FUN = function(x) rollmeanr(x, 3, fill = NA)))
```

Comment: Greetings to both of you )

Comment: I am sorry but why I have got the error  "Error in drop && !has.j : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y' "  while applying to my original data

Comment: I have found `caTools` to be by far the fastest package for rolling means

Answer (score 5):

You can use the base function `filter`.

```
z[ , moving_average := filter(x, rep(1/3, 3), sides = 1), by = "y"]
```

Note that a lag of 3 results in *two* `NA`s.

Comment: Ohhh, yes. I was so hurry that I made two stupid mistakes. I ll correct them now.

Comment: I have found filter to be more robust than rollmean when used in conjunction with data.table