# How to compute daily average over 31 days for 15 years, taking into account missing values?

Tags: r

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34508834/how-to-compute-daily-average-for-15-years) was marked as duplicate. I don't think it is a duplicate because the specific issues of

- averaging over a time span measured in days for several years
- and of missing data

Have not been dealt with elsewhere.
I have worked on an answer which I am not allowed to paste in the original question. Therefore I paste it here.

> Based on daily data for `15 years  from 1993 to 2008`. How to compute the daily average, for the variable `Open` in the file, for each day of the year, based on a 31 day Window centred on the day of interest. Thus, `15⨯31 = 465 dates` contribute to the statistics of one day.
>
> Output is just 365 values out of the 15 years
>
> The file can be downloaded from here:
> http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=sbux&a=2&b=01&c=1993&d=2&e=01&f=2008&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=sbux&x=.csv

Answer (score 2):

Load packages and data

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
dtf <- read.csv("http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=sbux&a=2&b=01&c=1993&d=2&e=01&f=2008&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=sbux&x=.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# I prefer lower case column names
names(dtf) <- tolower(names(dtf))
```

The lubridate package has a nice function ddays() that adds a number of days. It deals with February 29. For example

```
ymd("2008-03-01") - ddays(15)
# [1] "2008-02-15 UTC"
ymd("2007-03-01") - ddays(15)
# [1] "2007-02-14 UTC"
```

Add minus15 and plus15 dates to the dataset, these will be the time bounds over which the average should be calculated for a given date in a given year.

```
dtf <- dtf %>% 
    mutate(date = ymd(date),
           minus15 = date - ddays(15),
           plus15 = date + ddays(15),
           monthday = substr(as.character(date),6,10),
           year = year(date),
           plotdate = ymd(paste(2008,monthday,sep="-"))) 

calendardays <- dtf %>% 
    select(monthday) %>% 
    distinct() %>%
    arrange(monthday)
```

Create a function that gives the average over all those 15 years for a given day :

```
meanday <- function(givenday, dtf){
    # Extract the given day minus 15 days in all years available
    # Day minus 15 days will differ for example for march first 
    # in years where there is a february 29
    lowerbound <- dtf$minus15[dtf$monthday == givenday]
    # Produce the series of 31 days around the given day
    # that is the lower bound + 30 days
    filterdates <- lapply(lowerbound, function(x) x + ddays(0:30))
    filterdates <- Reduce(c, filterdates)
    # filter all of these days 
    dtfgivenday <- dtf %>%
        filter(date %in% filterdates) 
    return(mean(dtfgivenday$open))
}
```

Use that function over all dates available in the calendar:

```
meandays <- sapply(calendardays$monthday, meanday, dtf)
calendardays <- calendardays %>% 
    mutate(mean = meandays,
           plotdate = ymd(paste(2008,monthday,sep="-")))
```

Plots

```
plot(dtf$date,dtf$open,type="l")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dtf, aes(x=date,y=open, color = as.factor(year))) + geom_line()
ggplot(dtf, aes(x=plotdate,y=open, color = as.factor(year))) + geom_line()
ggplot(calendardays, aes(x=plotdate, y=mean)) + geom_line()
```

[image: Time series]

[image: All series on one year]

[image: Plot of the moving average]

Is it strange to see a periodicity appear here?

Comment: The final plot represents the average of all moving averages ? for instance:For a date 2008-02-07 you take the average of 31 days (15 before and 15 after). You do the same for 2007-02-07 and 2006-02-07...and so on for all year days (all seventh of February). then you average all these values to get final value   for 02-07? Is this what you done in your answer?

Comment: Yes in a way, except that it's not an average of averages, but rather an average over 15*31 = 465 values directly. There are 15 time windows of 31 days: 15 days before and 15 days after 2008-02-07, the same for 2007-02-07 and 2006-02-07...and so on. `meanday("02-07")` returns the average of the `open` variable within the 15 time windows.

Comment: I guess this the final values:`> head(meandays)
   01-02    01-03    01-04    01-05    01-06    01-07 
27.78185 29.25146 32.05867 34.79089 33.76463 32.12979 `.   Is it possible to have it in tow cols named   `date   value`

Comment: Last thing:I need to subtract all original values from this average,for instance,all seventh of February - this value `02-07`, all eighth of February - this value `02-08`  and so on ...