# R and Zoo: moving average with ragged data?

Tags: r, zoo, moving-average, ragged

I want to calculate moving averages to fill the NA entries with the known entries 3, 5 and 1. How can I do this with the package zoo in R?

**Input**

```
> library(zoo)
> hh <- c(NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, 5, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA)
```

**Fails**

> *Fail with rollmean*
>
> ```
>     > rollmean(hh,na.omit=TRUE,k=1)
>      [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
>     > rollmean(hh,4, na.omit=TRUE,k=1)
>      [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
>     > rollmean(hh,4, na.rm=TRUE,k=1)
>      [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
> ```
>
> *Fail with Rollapply*
>
> ```
>     > rollapply(hh, 4, function(x) mean(x))
>     [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
> ```

**Intended output something like**

> ```
>     > COMMAND(hh, movingAverageNumber, function(x) mean(x))
>     [1] 3 3.3 3.4 3 4 5 3 1 2 1.5 1.2 1 0.8
> ```

**Related**

1. [Using rollmean when there are missing values (NA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765001/using-rollmean-when-there-are-missing-values-na)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're looking for, What about:

```
   rollapply(hh, 5, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
   [1] 3 4 4 3 3 3 1 1
```

or

```
   rollapply(hh, 4, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
   [1]   3   3   4   4   3   3   1   1 NaN
```

Comment: +1 for getting the commands running :) How would you fill the ends of hh? hh has 12 elements while the former candidate here has 8 elements while the latter candidate here has 9 elements (with one NaN. Is there any option to fill NaN values with some default such as 1?

Comment: @Rhodo both functions generate an error.  With the output shown the argument that is set should be `width` and not `by`

Comment: @ReganAlpha I would suggest typing `?rollapply` and look for an argument called `fill`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the rolling `mean` for four values (you pass `k=1` to `rollmean`), you need to tell `mean` to drop the `NA`

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(hh, 4, function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))

[1]   3   3   4   4   3   3   1   1 NaN
```

Although this returns something different than your desired output.  You'll need to explain this further if you want something different.